# Asking a manager to reconsider the date of a decision without seeming pushy

Tags: manager, hiring

I'm currently on a year long placement at a company that hasn't yet offered me a graduate position but it's very likely that they will. My placements ends at the start of June and I would be going back to finish University in September, this means I have 3 months over summer which I'd like to spend working for the company.

I've already raised this option with my manager in my mid placement review in mid-December (maybe not the best time, not sure?) and he was open to the idea saying they they've done it before. However when I mentioned it again in early January (probably too early given the down-time over the holiday period) wondering if anything had been brought up he said that we would "look for opportunities around May" at which time we would have a better idea of the places available and the budget which is reasonable. I think I've also mentioned it slightly more off-hand since then, my manager mentioned he had it noted down.

My issue here is that in my opinion May is cutting it very close to the end of my placement to be making that decision. From a personal side if I wasn't working there over summer I'd need to move to my university's city to save money and finding a place to live and signing contracts and arranging moving dates etc in less than 4 weeks is a tall order. From the business side, since I would be a short term contractor instead of a placement student that might also make re-doing background checks necessary and things like that which could run over the 4 week period which could mean a week or two away from work which wouldn't be ideal.

I want to ask my manager if we can move this decision up from May for the reasons above, but given that I've already asked about it once or twice in the past two months I don't want to come across as though I'm pressuring a decision (if forced into a decision I suspect it would be 'no' to stick on the safe side of the budget) or that I'm being pushy at all. How can I go about asking this without seeming like I'm nagging my manager?

As an aside, is my request reasonable in the first place?
Would I need to consider asking from a more business oriented perspective? It feels like the reasons I gave are from a more personal perspective while not showing how the business benefits.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't approach the manager with, 'can I change your mind?' Approach the manager with, 'I'm in a bit of a personal dilemma due to the decision-making schedule for placements, what do you suggest?' There's really nothing very special about the details of your situation; issues come up all the time. It could be that there is a giant set of machinery behind the scenes here that your manager can't change even if he wants to. It could be, on the other hand, that once he understands your reasons for asking, that it is possible to do something for you. You can only find out by asking.

No sane person is going to be offended or feel pressured by a coop/intern asking a question like this at 30-day intervals.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, that phrasing changes the entire tone of the question, I prefer that. Also you referred to the manager as a she, I couldn't edit it because it was just a 1 character change.

Answer (score 0):

You want to do this "without being pushy". Why? If two people want this position, the pushy one will get it. If one wants it, and that one is you, you may end up with the boss saying "sorry, it's too late now, you should have reminded me earlier". Be pushy.

You go to your manager and say (something like) "Hey boss, you may not realise this, but I need to know whether I will get this job, and I will need to know this soon. If I don't get it, then I'll have to completely change my plans for the next week, and if I get it then HR will want to be informed as early as possible. So please tell me by the end of the week at latest. If I don't hear from you before, I'll ask you on Friday. I don't want to go without this job just because the decision took too late".

With some people, nothing happens until they are put under pressure. They leave things to the last possible moment. You just told them the last possible moment is Friday. This will help you with that kind of person.